# Create pagination from gii code generation in yii2

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I have use Gii to generate my code.

Now, I want to display the table in view into pagination.
So, I use like this :

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new BarangSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $countDataProvider = clone $dataProvider;


    $paging = new \yii\data\Pagination([
        'totalCount' => $countDataProvider->count(),
        'defaultPageSize' => 5
    ]);


    return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'paging' => $paging
    ]);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php
Pjax::begin([
    'timeout' => 5000,
    'id' => 'pjax-gridview'
]);
?>

<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'NO_URUT',
        'CONSIGNEE',
        'CONTAINER',
        'SIZE',
        'COIL_NO',
        'NET',
        'GROSS',
        'CONTRACT_NO',
        'KET',
        'NAMA_FILE',
        'TGL_UNSTUFF',
        'CREATED_AT',
        'UPDATED_AT',
        [
            'attribute' => 'CREATED_BY',
            'value' => function($data) {
                $username_created_by = $data->CREATED_BY;
                if ($user = User::findIdentity($data->CREATED_BY)):
                    $username_created_by = $user->username;
                endif;
            }
        ],
        'UPDATED_BY',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
?>
```

It gives me error like this :

```
Calling unknown method: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::count()
```

What best practice to implement pagination in gii2, and I want to use pjax to manage this pagination too.

For the help. it so appreciated

Comment: Try `getTotalCount()` instead of `count()`

Comment: what about in index, I create : <?=
    \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination' => $paging
    ]);
    ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?></div> 
  
    just create index of pagination, not the paginate itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `pageSize` of the `dataProvider` like this:

```
$dataProvider->pagination = [
    'pageSize' => 5,
];
```

If you have `Pjax::begin` and `Pjax::end` between the `GridView` then pagination will use Pjax automatically.

For more details you can see [**here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html).

Comment: Thanks, but where am I to put : $dataProvider->pagination = [
    'pageSize' => 5,
];

Comment: Just after: $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kostas, it working now :

The final code like this :

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new BarangSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination = [
        'pageSize' => 2,
    ];

    return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Consider look at kartik's GridView too. You can find it here: http://demos.krajee.com/grid